# RelativeLayout distribution issues

Tags: android, android-layout

I have to design a list item with this given distribution of it's inner components

[image: desired layout]

I'm trying with a relative layout because every ImageView is fixed size and TextView should cover the remaining space in my list item, whose width is match_parent. (any better ideas are welcome!)

So my code right now is this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/appcontrols_customerhistory_operation"
        android:id="@+id/operationsDoneOperationIcon" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/appcontrols_customerhistory_operation"
        android:id="@+id/operationsDoneChevronIcon" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/operationsDoneChevronIcon"
        android:src="@drawable/appcontrols_customerhistory_operation"
        android:id="@+id/operationsDoneStatusIcon" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/operationsAvailableItemName"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat."
        android:maxLines="4"
        android:lines="4"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/operationsDoneOperationIcon"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/operationsDoneStatusIcon" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But result is not the one I want to achieve.. here a screenshot:

[image: actual layout]

Any ideas of what am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should use `linear layout` with orientation as `horizontal`. use weight to specify width to each view inside `linear layout`.

Comment: yes, that idea came to my mind but it doesn't give the text view all the remaining space.. I just have to set a possible width which looks good but i could do it setting each width in dp also..

Comment: to `linearlayout` give `weightsum=5` then `weight=1` to each `imageView` and `2` to `tv`

Comment: that just give 20% of the width to each image and 40% to text view, it's a good approach but not exactly what I want to achieve

Comment: ok. i'll ask you to try to work around and see. also check with your requirements.